# websocket handshake: developer need to do anything for this?

Tags: websocket, handshake

I have successfully completed my websocket test, but I want to know about Websocket handshake. In my web client I have used the below code to start websocket communication

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com/foobar");
ws.onmessage = function(evt) { /* some code */ }
ws.send("Hello World")
```

In my web server (used Java) I have used Jetty lib and implemented server like below:

```
public class MyWebSocket implements WebSocket.OnTextMessage {
    public void onOpen(Connection connection)
    {
    }

    public void onMessage(byte frame, byte[] data,int offset, int length)
    {
    }

    public void onMessage(String data)
    {
    }

    public void onClose(int code, String message)
    {

    }
}
```

Web socket communication working fine for me, I have not done anything for handshake. How it is working?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a library like Jetty, repetitive things like handshaking is done behind the scenes so that you don't have to take care of that. That's the idea of using libraries - you can write straight-forward code without having to reinvent the wheel.

If you do want to implement handshaking yourself, you might want to fiddle around *without* a library and play around as to how to implement it "barely".

For Jetty, you can view the handshaking code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-websocket/7.4.0.v20110414/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketConnectionD06.java#693), and the key parsing is done [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-websocket/7.4.0.v20110414/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketConnectionD06.java#714).